# Regex group match and replacement in a single statement

Tags: regex, scala

I am using a code generation tool and I need to convert method calls like this (it's java):

```
public MyObjectType MyObjectType(){
```

into a more java-fied version:

```
public MyObjectType myObjectType(){
```

I have this working snippet of Scala code that does that:

```
val pattern = """[\s]+public[\s]+[\w]+[\s]+([\w]+\(\))\{""".r

val tmp = pattern.findAllIn(s).matchData map { m =>
  val x = m.group(1).replaceAll("\\(\\)", "\\\\(\\\\)")
  s.replaceAll(x, firstLowerCase(x))
}
// if there is no match, return unmodified string,
// otherwise return the only match
val converted = if (tmp.isEmpty) s else tmp.next()
```

Where `s` is one line of code, possible candidate for the transformation.

The function `firstLowerCase` is defined as:

```
def firstLowerCase(s: String): String = {
  val (first, rest) = s.splitAt(1)
  first.toLowerCase + rest
}
```

The code above works fine, but I was wondering if it was possible to slim it down a bit (ideally to a single pattern match statement), e.g., by (somehow) removing the explicit conversion of `()` to `\(\)`, doing the match and replace in one shot or incorporating the above function in the replacement. I am not a regex expert so maybe this is too much to ask. Ideas?

Comment: make it simple for us. What's the subject and the desired output?

Comment: I'll clarify my question and subject.

Comment: I hope that's clearer.

Comment: You want to convert this `()` into this `\(\)` ? or the other way around ?

Comment: I have to, otherwise the statement `s.replaceAll(x, firstLowerCase(x))` does not work because `()` is interpreted as a group.

Comment: Well ultimately I want to convert `MyObjectType()` to `myObjectType()`, but I can't just match `MyObjectType` because I don't want to convert the type, only the method name. Needless to say `MyObjectType` can be a lot of different types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
val pattern = """(public\s+\w+\s+)(\w)(?=\w*\(\)\{)""".r
val converted = pattern.replaceAllIn(s, m => m.group(1) + m.group(2).toLowerCase)
```

`replaceAllIn` makes it unnecessary to do a `findAllIn` and then go back and do a `replaceAll`. We match the beginning part of the pattern, the character we need to lower case, and then handle the rest with a look ahead assertion (we don't need to replace it, only confirm that it is present). The replacement text is the beginning of the pattern and that single character made lowercase, `firstLowerCase` isn't needed.

Comment: I actually ended up using `(public\s+\w+\s+)(\w)(\w+\s*\(\)\s*\{)` and then `m => m.group(1) + m.group(2).toLowerCase + m.group(3)`, it makes it a little clearer.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be doing what you need. I've also made the pattern a bit more flexible e.g. in that spaces are allowed before the `{`.

```
import scala.util.matching.Regex

// wingedsubmariner's answer actually has a better pattern
val Pattern = """(public\s+\w+\s+)(\w+)(\s*\(\)\s*\{)""".r

def firstLowerCase(s: String): String = {
  val (first, rest) = s.splitAt(1)
  first.toLowerCase + rest
}

val lines = List(
  "public MyObjectType MyObjectTypeMeth(){",
  " public MyObjectType MyObjectTypeMeth(){   ",
  "public MyObjectType MyObjectTypeMeth() {",
  "public MyObjectType MyObjectTypeMeth () {")

lines.foreach { s =>
  val converted = Pattern.replaceAllIn(s, m => {
    m.group(1) + firstLowerCase(m.group(2)) + m.group(3)
  })

  println(converted)
}
```

**output:**

```
public MyObjectType myObjectTypeMeth(){
 public MyObjectType myObjectTypeMeth(){   
public MyObjectType myObjectTypeMeth() {
public MyObjectType myObjectTypeMeth () {
```

Comment: What happens if there is no match? I'm not familiar with the API. Works like a charm though! Thanks

Comment: nothing of course; `replaceAllIn` will invoke the passed in function for each match... no matches, no invocations.

Comment: I like @wingedsubmariner's path however now every line is a match, e.g., try adding to the list of lines `private MyObjectType iMyObjectType;`. However the line doesn't get modified in those cases.

Comment: Also with the pattern `(public\s+\w+\s+)(\w)(\w+\s*\(\)\s*\{)` you actually don't need to call `firstLowerCase`, just `toLowerCase` on the second capture group.

Comment: I already commented that the other pattern is better; but I didn't get the `iMyObjectType` remark.

Comment: I just meant for some reason the pattern matches any line of input, although the capture groups don't always match.

Comment: why do you think that?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I was printing out the wrong thing. My Scala is too rusty! Works fine!